# Imprimindo DataGridView multiplas

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, impressão

Estou criando um relatório em vb.net com os dados da minha DataGrid  e tentando enviar para a impressão.
Porem neste projeto estou usando duas DataGrids , uma para uma tabela Relatori , e outra para a tabela Relatorio.

o código que geralmente uso para a impressão de uma DataGrid seria este :

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim PosicaoLinha As Integer = 40
    Dim LinhasPorPagina As Byte = 45
    Dim total As String = String.Empty
    Dim grupo As String = String.Empty
    Dim valor As String = String.Empty
    Dim unidade As String = String.Empty
    'Definições da pagina
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter
    'Desenhar folha
    Dim Titulo As New Font("Arial", 4, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter)
    g.DrawString("*** Resumo de vendas por Grupo *** ", Titulo, Brushes.Black, 10, 20)

    For L = 0 To LinhasPorPagina - 1
        If LinhaAtual = RELATORIDataGridView.Rows.Count Then Continue For
        For i As Integer = 0 To RELATORIDataGridView.ColumnCount - 5

            If Not RELATORIDataGridView.Item(i, LinhaAtual).Value = Nothing Then
                grupo = RELATORIDataGridView.Item(i, LinhaAtual).Value

            End If
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To RELATORIDataGridView.ColumnCount - 3

            If Not RELATORIDataGridView.Item(i, LinhaAtual).Value = Nothing Then
                unidade = RELATORIDataGridView.Item(i, LinhaAtual).Value

            End If
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To RELATORIDataGridView.ColumnCount - 4
            RELATORIDataGridView.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"
            If Not RELATORIDataGridView.Item(i, LinhaAtual).Value = Nothing Then
                valor = RELATORIDataGridView.Item(i, LinhaAtual).Value
            End If
        Next
        'Desenhar conteudo na página
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Grupo", New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 20, 30)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(grupo, New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 20, PosicaoLinha)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Unidades", New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 40, 30)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(unidade, New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 40, PosicaoLinha)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Valor", New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 60, 30)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(valor, New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 60, PosicaoLinha)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________", New Font("Verdana", 8), Brushes.Black, 0, 34)
        PosicaoLinha += 5
        LinhaAtual += 1
        valor = String.Empty
        grupo = String.Empty
        unidade = String.Empty
        total = String.Empty
    Next
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Totais: ", New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 20, PosicaoLinha)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lblTotalUnidade.Text, New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 40, PosicaoLinha)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lblTotalValor.Text, New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 60, PosicaoLinha)
End Sub
```

Alguem poderia me dizer como incluo mais uma DataGrid neste código para a impressão ?

Caso importe , estou utilizando Access como base.